# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `ThemeProvider`, expected a ReactNode

Tags: next.js, material-ui, next.js13

I'm using `Next.js 13.4` with `MUI 5`.
I created `not-found.tsx` file in app dir
when i visited random route, it is showing me result as defined styles.

im not sure whats causing this, i tried looking searching for this error but not results found.

`not-found.tsx`

```
'use client';
import { Box, Typography } from '@mui/material';

const NotFound = () => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <Typography variant='h1'>404</Typography>
      <Typography variant='h3'>Page Not Found</Typography>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default NotFound;
```

`layout.tsx`

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <Providers>
      <html lang='en'>
        <body className={inter.className}>
          <Navbar />
          <ThemeRegistry options={{ key: 'mui' }}>{children}</ThemeRegistry>
        </body>
      </html>
    </Providers>
  );
}
```

but also logging error in console.

```
app-index.js:31 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `ThemeProvider`, expected a ReactNode.
    at ThemeProvider (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@mui/material/styles/ThemeProvider.js:26:14)
    at ThemeRegistry (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./src/app/components/ThemeRegistry.tsx:25:13)
    at body
    at html
    at Provider
```